# Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout - UART connection issues

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been experiencing problems setting up the Ultimate GPS Breakout on a Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian.  I followed the tutorial found on the Adafruit web page, found here:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/introduction

For the project I am working on it is required that UART needs to be implemented instead of a USB transmission.  Through following the tutorial, I was unable to get the module to work yesterday as it keeps giving me a "NO FIX" status, even after an hour of waiting.  It did not matter how many times I typed the following into the terminal, as per the suggestions on other tutorials or forums:

```
$ sudo killall gpsd
$ sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
$ cgps -s
```

After two hours, after much frustration, I decided to take a break. After the break, I returned to the Raspberry Pi where I restarted the device and ran the previously mentioned command lines, and miraculously it worked. After another hour of so of playing around with the data via Python 2.7, the GPS dropped connection and has not returned.

Killing the command using Ctrl-C yields the following message:

```
cgps: caught signal_2
```

I have no clue what's wrong with it after countless attempts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the power supply for the GPS board from? A power supply issue might explain why it came right after a while if that side of things is repeatable.

Comment: I'm currently getting the power from the raspberry pi's breakouts.  I will try to externally power it and see if that fixes it. Thank you.